# window parallelism in Apache storm

Tags: apache-storm

I want to parallelize the window operation in Apache storm or in other words distributed window operation. I need to compare the performance when we run the window in single node and when we distribute its operation in multiple nodes distributively. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "parallelize the window operation"? Windows are not shared across workers.

Comment: Ok so if the window is in single node then whole operation will be done in that node with one window but if we have multiple nodes and need to parallelize this operation among multiple nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share the window across multiple workers.

If you're happy with having multiple concurrent windows, you can just increase the number of executors running your windowed bolt. You do this by setting the `parallellism_hint` parameter of `setBolt` to some number other than 1. This could be fine if your window is count based, but if it's time based you will get multiple windows for the same time interval (one per bolt).

If you instead want to parallellize the work done on the window, you could have a windowed bolt that creates the window, but does no other work, and then have it distribute the created windows among bolts that do the actual work.

e.g.

```
setBolt("window", new YourWindowedBolt().withWindow(...))
  .shuffleGrouping("your-spout");
setBolt("work", new YourProcessWindowBolt(), 5)
  .setTasks(5)
  .shuffleGrouping("window");
```

and then your windowed bolt execute would be something like

```
execute(TupleWindow window) {
  //Emit the entire window as one tuple to next bolt
  List<Tuple> tuples = window.get();
  Values values = new Values(new ArrayList<Tuple>(tuples));
  collector.emit(tuples, values);
}
```